# Reference column in another data frame by row entry

Tags: r

I have DF1 like this:

```
ID      Name      Team
222717  Bob       Badgers
321817  James     Tigers
521917  Eric      Possums
```

And DF2 like this:

```
Badgers    Tigers    Possums
222717     438283    521917
789423     978748    251233
```

I want to check if the ID in DF1 appears in the corresponding team name in DF2. For example, in the first row, Bob's ID does appear under his team name, "Badgers," in DF2. James' ID does not appear under his team name, "Tigers," in DF2. I was thinking of adding a column that marks whether it appears or not, but can't figure out how to reference the column in DF2. Here's what I tried.

```
test <- mutate(DF1,validID=ifelse(ID%in%DF2$DF1$Team,"Yes",NA))
```

The `DF2$DF1$Team` part is where I'm stuck. How do I reference the column in DF2 that corresponds to the team listed in DF1? Also open to alternative suggestions on how to manipulate the data to achieve this task.

Comment: Use the  `match` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%in%` function is a compact way to access the `match` function. `mapply` is the canonical method to supply multiple columns for evaluation of their corresponding values in sequence.

```
DF1$right2 <- mapply( function(a,b) {a %in% DF2[[b]]}, a=DF1$ID, b=as.character(DF1$Team) )
#============
> DF1
      ID  Name    Team right2
1 222717   Bob Badgers   TRUE
2 321817 James  Tigers  FALSE
3 521917  Eric Possums   TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks. I see how this is supposed to work, but when I run it I receive a "Error in DF2[[b]] : subscript out of bounds" error. DF2 is actually a list, not a DF despite the fact that I mistakenly said it was a DF. It's a list because I'm dealing with columns of different sizes. When I enter `DF2[["Badgers"]]`, I do see the correct info in the console.

Any ideas as to why this may be happening? Do I have to add as.character() somewhere?

Comment: Update: adding `as.character` worked.

`DF1$right2 <- mapply( function(a,b) {a %in% DF2[[as.character(b)]]}, a=DF1$ID, b=DF1$Team )`

Comment: Thanks for the update. Factor variable bite us again.  The `as.character` could also be applied to the b argument. See correction.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I find `mapply` hard to conceptualise, and in any case 42's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47878012/7028459) seems to return FALSE for Eric, when it ought to return true. Most likely a typo, but for future reference it's helpful to give your sample data in a format that lets you just copy the code and create the right objects!

This is a quick way of doing it avoiding `map` or `apply` functions, with only `tidyverse` tools (and a `magrittr` alias, but you can sub that out). Here I split the "finding the right column" and "checking if ID is there" into two steps, but you could combine if you wanted.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
df1 <- tibble(ID = c(222717, 321817, 521917),
              Name = c("Bob", "James", "Eric"),
              Team = c("Badgers", "Tigers", "Possums")
              )
df2 <- tibble(Badgers = c(222717, 789423),
              Tigers = c(438283, 978748),
              Possums = c(521917, 251233)
              )
df1 %>%
  mutate(team_col = colnames(df2) %>% equals(Team) %>% which()) %>%
  mutate(id_exists_for_team = ID %in% as_vector(df2[team_col]))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>       ID  Name    Team team_col id_exists_for_team
#>    <dbl> <chr>   <chr>    <int>              <lgl>
#> 1 222717   Bob Badgers        1               TRUE
#> 2 321817 James  Tigers        2              FALSE
#> 3 521917  Eric Possums        3               TRUE
```

Comment: Maybe tibble-handling functions deal with factor columns more cleanly? We apparently have significantly different programming models. `mapply` does a "parallel" item-by-item application of the data arguments. It was a factor needing as.character. There's a 1-1 correspondence between your first mutate and the use of as.character(DF1$Team) to select the column for testing. And there's a 1-1 correspondence between using %in% to return a single logical value per DF1$ID. I don't think `map` (assuming you mean purrr::map)  is really analogous to `mapply`.  It only takes a single column.

Comment: `mapply` is really closer to what most people expect `apply` to do.

Comment: I think `map` is like `apply`, and `map2` might be like `mapply`? Not too familiar though. Yeah, I can parse through it but I always feel like I need pencil and paper for it